# Proving inequality for a recurrence

Tags: solution-verification, induction, recurrence-relations, recursion

**The Question is as Follows:**

Define the sequence of numbers Ai by:

A(0) = 2

$A\left(n+1\right)\ =\ \frac{A\left(n\right)}{2}+\frac{1}{A\left(n\right)}$  (for n≥ 1)

Prove that $A\left(n\right)\ \le\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ for n >= 0

**My Proof:**

Proof by induction: P(n): $A\left(n\right)\ \le\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}$

Basecase: n = 0

$A(0) = 2 \le\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{0}}$

So base case is true.

Inductive Step:

Assuming $A\left(n\right)\ \le\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ to prove $A\left(n+1\right)\ \le\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{\left(n+1\right)}}.$

By induction hypothesis:

$A\left(n\right)\ \le\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}$

The limit as n goes to infinity A(n) goes to $\sqrt{2}$. it converges to $\sqrt{2}$. This means as n increases A(n) gets smaller and smaller and gets closer to $\sqrt{2}$. This means:

$A\left(n\right)\ \ge\ A\left(n+1\right)$

Which means:

$A\left(n+1\right)\ \le\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}$

We now claim:

$A\left(n+1\right)\ \le\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{\left(n+1\right)}}$

Proof by contradiction: For the sake of contradiction assume the opposite:

$A\left(n+1\right)\ \ge\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$

let n = n - 1

$A\left(n\right)\ \ge\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}$

But this contradicts inductive hypothesis. Therefore:

$A\left(n+1\right)\ \le\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{\left(n+1\right)}}$

Hence Proven.

**Is my Proof correct?**

Comment: No, not even close. Note that you never made use of the given recursion.

Comment: @roadrunner Can you explain?

Comment: Where did you use the given recursion?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of using induction is correct, but the induction step has mistakes:

- We cannot conclude $A(n)\geq A(n+1)$ solely from $A(n)\leq\sqrt2+2^{-n}$, because this condition only shows the upper bound of $A(n)$ is decreasing, but this does not mean $A(n)$ itself is decreasing.
- The claim is $A(n+1)\leq\sqrt2+2^{-(n+1)}$, so to prove by contradiction we need to assume $A(n+1)>\sqrt2+2^{-(n+1)}$ but not $A(n+1)\geq\sqrt2+2^{-n}$ as in your step.

---

To solve these issues, we need to at least use the recursion. Here are some ideas:

- Change the claim to $\sqrt2<A(n)\leq \sqrt2+2^{-n}$.
- Show that $f(x)=x/2+1/x$ is increasing when $x>\sqrt2$.
- Since $f$ is increasing and $\sqrt2<A(n)\leq\sqrt2+2^{-n}$, we have $$A(n+1)=f(A(n))> f(\sqrt2)\ \text{and similarly}\ A(n+1)\leq f(\sqrt2+2^{-n})$$
- Show that $f(\sqrt2)\geq\sqrt2$.
- Show that $f(\sqrt2+2^{-n})\leq\sqrt2+2^{-(n+1)}$.
- The induction step $\sqrt2<A(n+1)\leq \sqrt2+2^{-(n+1)}$ is then verified.

Comment: Thanks for you response:). I'm not concluding that () ≥ (+1) from () ≤ √2 + 2^(-). I'm saying if you take the limit as n goes to infinity, A(n) goes to √2. it converges to √2. This means as n increases A(n) gets smaller and smaller and gets closer to √2. From this fact I concluded:
() ≥ (+1)

Comment: You are welcome, the issue is that by taking $n\to\infty$ we only know the upper bound of $A(n)$ converges to $\sqrt2$, but this does not mean $A(n)$ itself converges to $\sqrt2$. (e.g. $A(n)$ could be an increasing sequence but still satisfies $A(n)\leq\sqrt2+2^{-n}$)

Comment: Hmmm... So you're saying that it does not necessarily follows that A(n) must be a decreasing sequence just because a function converges to √2 as n -> infinity, right? but then my response would be that since the starting value of the sequence A(0) is bigger than √2 therefore it must now mean that it is a decreasing sequence and that A(n) >= A(n+1).

Comment: It is true $A(0)\geq\sqrt2$, but we do not know whether $A(n)\geq\sqrt2$ for all $n$, we need to rigorously show this, which is one of the steps in this answer post.

Comment: Besides, even if we know $A(n)\geq\sqrt2$ for all $n$, it still does not imply $A(n)$ is decreasing. You can easily construct a sequence such that $A(0)=2$, $\sqrt2\leq A(n)\leq\sqrt2+2^{-n}$ and $A(n)<A(n+1)$ for infinitely many $n$. To get around this issue, we have to use the given recursion.

Comment: You said "(0)≥ √2, but we do not know whether ()≥ √2 for all ". I don't get this. if the starting value of the sequence A(n) is 2 and the limit of A(n) as n -> ∞ is √2 then that means as n gets larger and larger the value of A(n) goes to √2 which means it's decreasing and thus A(n) <= A(n+1). The fact that A(0) = 2 coupled with the fact that limit is √2 implies that it is decreasing because the starting value is higher and as n increase it gets lower. No?

Comment: I think there is a confusion, let's clarify it first. So your argument is that $A(0)=2$ and $A(n)\leq\sqrt2+2^{-n}$ for all $n$ imply $A(n)\geq A(n+1)$ right? (Is there any extra condition that I am missing in your argument besides $A(0)=2$ and $A(n)\leq\sqrt2+2^{-n}$?)

Comment: My argument is as follows: We know the starting value of the sequence A(n), which is 2. The limit of A(n) as n -> ∞ goes to √2.  Therefore this means that as n increases A(n) decreases which means A(n) >= A(n+1). That's all I'm saying.

Comment: For this statement 'The limit of $A(n)$ as $n\to\infty$ goes to $\sqrt2$', do you conclude this solely from $A(0)=2$ and $A(n)\leq\sqrt2+2^{-n}$? (Or you are using other conditions?)

Comment: No I don't conclude it from this. I can prove it separately and I have even though I didn't included it in the original proof.

Comment: The key is that did you use the recursion relation in your proof of 'the limit of $A(n)$ as goes to $\sqrt2$'?

Comment: Yes I did. I did the proof similar to this one shown in the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-6ddh2bxFQ

Comment: Okay this checks out. So you proved that $A(n)\to\sqrt2$, and then conclude that $A(n)$ gets closer and closer from above to $\sqrt2$ and therefore $A(n)$ is decreasing?

Comment: yes that's what I did.

Comment: The issue is $A(n)\to\sqrt2$ does not mean $A(n)$ gets closer to $\sqrt2$ in **every** step. It could get further away from $\sqrt2$ at some steps and then eventually get back to $\sqrt2$. In those 'away' steps, $A(n)$ would be increasing and therefore we need more than $A(0)=2$ and $A(n)\to\sqrt2$ to show $A(n)$ is decreasing. (Unless you already proved that $A(n)$ gets closer in **every** step, but that basically means $A(n)$ is decreasing)

Comment: Hmmm... got it. But this question was part of mit discrete math course where it was mentioned that we ignore recursions that oscillates. So given that then it checks out, No?

Comment: Sorry but just a side note, it would be really good if you could add such context information (like you are ignoring oscillating recursions) into your future questions, because then we will know much better what you are looking for, and provide a better answer.

Comment: I do apologize, I should have had. I didn't include the limit proof as I considered it something to be proven easily.

Comment: Back to the question, suppose now we proved $A(n)$ is decreasing to $\sqrt2$ and $A(n)\leq\sqrt2+2^{-n}$, but this is not enough for $A(n+1)\leq\sqrt2+2^{-(n+1)}$ because $A(n+1)$ could lie between these two bounds (i.e. $\sqrt2+2^{-(n+1)}<A(n+1)\leq\sqrt2+2^{-n}$)

Comment: No problem at all, I am also sorry for not getting what you mean in the first place

Comment: This discussion is going really well but it's getting quite late here in my city and I'm about to go to sleep. Can we continue this conversation around the same time tomorrow? :)

Comment: I think what we need is not only $A(n)$ is decreasing, but the recursion $f(x)=x/2+1/x$ is decreasing as $x$ decreases, only then we can conclude the induction step as shown in the answer.

Comment: No worries, we could leave messages any time!

Comment: great! We would continue tomorrow:)

Comment: okay so back to this. First I have shown that A(n) <= √2 + 2^−. This is true by induction hypothesis. Secondly I have that A(n) is decreasing sequence based on the fact that the starting value of the sequence i.e A(0) = 2 and the fact that the limit of () as →∞ goes to √2 (even though the proof of the limit was not included in the answer)

Comment: Now since it is decreasing sequence that means A(n) >= A(n+1). So by transitivity $A\left(n+1\right)\ \le\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ . The we claim that: $A\left(n+1\right)\ \le\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{\left(n+1\right)}}$ and this is proven by contradiction in the answer

Comment: Hi welcome back. In the contradiction argument, you assumed $A(n+1)\geq\sqrt2+2^{-n}$ and conclude this is impossible due to contradiction, however this only shows $A(n+1)<\sqrt2+2^{-n}$ but not $A(n+1)\leq\sqrt2+2^{-(n+1)}$, so $A(n)$ could still lie between $\sqrt2+2^{-n}$ and $\sqrt2+2^{-(n+1)}$

Comment: Oh sorry! that was typing mistake. I fixed it now. I actually meant $A\left(n+1\right)\ \le\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{\left(n+1\right)}}$

Comment: No worries. The issue is if we assume by contradiction that $A(n+1)>\sqrt2+\frac1{2^{n+1}}$, I am not sure how do we show this contradicts $A(n)\leq\sqrt2+\frac1{2^n}$?

Comment: We have shown that by saying if we then let n = n -1 and plug that in $A\left(n+1\right)\ \le\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{\left(n+1\right)}}$ we get $A\left(n\right)\ \ge\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}$. This contradicts induction hypothesis because we assumed the opposite in induction hypothesis.

Comment: The logic of induction is that we assume $A(m)\leq\sqrt2+1/(2^m)$ for all $m\leq n$ for some fixed $n$, and we do not assume anything about $A(n+1)$, so $A(n+1)\geq\sqrt2+\frac1{2^{n+1}}$ will not contradict $A(n)\leq\sqrt2+1/(2^n)$ because all the assumptions stop at $m\leq n$. I am not sure if this is clear?

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But that's not what I'm saying in the proof by contradiction. In the proof by contradiction, by assuming the opposite I arrived at the conclusion that $A\left(n\right)\ \ge\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ which contradicts induction hypothesis. I'm referring to A(n) not A(n+1).

Comment: The induction step is $A(n+1)\leq\sqrt2+2^{-(n+1)}$, so the 'opposite' is $A(n+1)>\sqrt2+2^{-(n+1)}$, but $A(n+1)>\sqrt2+2^{-(n+1)}$ does not imply $A(n)\geq A(n+1)>\sqrt2+2^{-n}$, so there is no contradiction invoked?

Comment: In the inductive step I'm trying to prove $A\left(n+1\right)\ \le\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{\left(n+1\right)}}$ by assuming $A\left(n\right)\ \le\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ as it is supposed to be in the inductive step. You assume something is true for n to prove something is also true for n+1 and that's what I did.

Comment: Where I am lost is, how does $A(n+1)>\sqrt2+\frac1{2^{n+1}}$ contradict $A(n)\leq\sqrt2+\frac1{2^{n}}$? Since the assumption stops at $A(n)$.

Comment: Hi:) You are right $A\left(n+1\right)\ \ge\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ doesn't contradict $A\left(n\right)\ \le\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}$. But that's not what I said in the prove. I make a claim $A\left(n+1\right)\ \le\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{\left(n+1\right)}}$ . Then I said I will prove this by contradiction by assuming the opposite. When I assumed the opposite I arrived at a contradiction i.e $A\left(n\right)\ \ge\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}$. This is what contradicts induction hypothesis.

Comment: @AzharKhan Hi, if we assume the opposite $A(n+1)>\sqrt2+2^{-(n+1)}$, I am lost how does this imply $A(n)>\sqrt2+2^{-(n)}$? Since $A$ is decreasing, I think $A(n+1)>\sqrt2+2^{-(n+1)}$ only implies $A(n)\geq A(n+1)>\sqrt2+2^{-(n+1)}$ but not $A(n)>\sqrt2+2^{-(n)}$.

Comment: In a proof by contradiction you assume the opposite of what you want to prove and if you then arrive at some contradiction that means your assumption is wrong and the original claim is true.  So in this case if we assumed the opposite and then let n = n-1 and plug that in $A\left(n+1\right)\ \ge\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{\left(n+1\right)}}\ $ we get $A\left(n\right)\ \ge\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ and this contradicts induction hypothesis, therefore our original claim $A\left(n+1\right)\ \le\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{\left(n+1\right)}}$ is true.

Comment: @AzharKhan The property $A(n+1)\geq\sqrt2+2^{-(n+1)}$ is not transitive, we cannot simply switch $n$ to $n-1$ and conclude $A(n)\geq\sqrt2+2^{-n}$, we have to use rigorous argument to prove this (e.g. by analysing the recursion).

Comment: Note that if it is transitive, then we can literally prove ANY induction step using this transitive idea. For example, we can even claim $A(n)\leq2^{1-n}$ which is true for $n=0$, then we assume the opposite for $A(n+1)>2^{1-(n+1)}$ and plug $n=n-1$ so $A(n)>2^{1-n}$, which gives contradiction. So $A(n)\leq2^{1-n}$, but this is of course wrong.

Comment: That's definitely a problem and something that did crossed my mind and thought this is something fishy but I could not understand why can't I switch to n-1 ,meaning I could not understood the logic of why doing such a thing is wrong.

Comment: You said $A\left(n+1\right)\ \ge\ \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$  is not transitive, but I'm not saying that either. That was something we assumed for the sake of contradiction as you would normally do in a proof by contradiction

Comment: Sorry but I mean it is not transitive in $n$, basically we cannot transit $n$ to $n-1$ and still have the same inequality to hold, that's the major issue

Comment: @AzharKhan As for why we cannot do this $n$ to $n-1$ trick, this is because $f(n)\geq g(n)$ does not imply $f(n-1)\geq g(n-1)$ in general for some function $f$ and $g$. Is this a clear statement?

Comment: hmmm.., I understand. Can you give me any link where I can look more into this or even better a video link where it might be explained.

Comment: So I kinda missed a step, for this to work  I also need to prove that in this case ()≥() does indeed imply (−1)≥(−1)

Comment: @AzharKhan I don't know if there is a source that specifically discusses the $n\to n-1$ issue, but you could try doing more practice on this type of inductions (e.g. [here](https://www.ms.uky.edu/~droyster/ma114F16/RecursiveSequences.pdf))

Comment: Yes you'll need that step. One way is to analyse the recursion $f(x)=x/2+1/x$ and obtain its decreasing/increasing property (similar as shown in the answer post), or you could come up with something different, it should be good as long as it works.

Comment: Hi, if we choose a specific $n$ and reach contradiction, then this will only work for that specific $n$. What I mean is, in your case, we choose $n=1$ and reach contradiction, but this contradiction only shows $A(1)\leq\sqrt2+1/2$, we do not know anything about $n>1$

Comment: @AzharKhan I feel you might have some confusion about mathematical induction. The logic of induction is that: 1. we fix some $n\in\mathbb N$ and **only** assume $A(n)\leq\sqrt2+2^{-n}$; 2. we use $A(n)\leq\sqrt2+2^{-n}$ and the recursion to deduce $A(n+1)\leq\sqrt2+2^{-(n+1)}$. During the induction, we keep $n$ general and do not choose a specific $n$, we also do not assume anything about $A(n+1)$.

Comment: Hi Zhang! :) Sorry if I'm bothering you with questions related to this problem. Basically I want to have my own unique proof for this problem and so I keep coming back to this problem once in a while.

Comment: @AzharKhan No worries at all! It is nice to seek our own proof, and you can leave message any time

Comment: Hi Zhang! :)  it's been great exchanging thoughts with you. If you're open to it, I'd love to stay in touch. Would you be comfortable sharing your preferred social media handle or any other way you'd prefer to connect?

Comment: @AzharKhan You could find my email address in my profile page, is that okay?

Comment: email is good too. Do you have discord? They have nice chat section

Comment: @AzharKhan Sorry I don't often use discord, we could probably continue our conversation in email first and explore some possibility there?

Comment: yes that's fine with me. If I have any questions or want to discuss some topic I will drop you an email :)

Comment: @AzharKhan Anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

If you allow yourself to use induction, then why not just look at entire closed form solution. The solution can be found as follows,

$$
a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}}{2}+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}
$$

This is almost in the form of the hyperbolic identity

$$
\coth 2\alpha=\frac{1+\coth^2\alpha}{2\coth\alpha}
$$

So, let $b_n=a_n/\sqrt{2}$, which leads to

$$
b_n=\frac{1+b_{n-1}^2}{2b_{n-1}}
$$

The let $b_n=\coth(c_n)$, which leads to

$$
\coth (c_n)=\frac{1+\coth^2(c_{n-1})}{2\coth (c_{n-1})}=\coth (2c_{n-1})
$$

Or,

$$
c_n=2c_{n-1}\\
c_n=c_02^n
$$

Thus, backing our way to $a_n$,

$$
b_n=\coth(c_n)=\coth(c_02^n)\\
a_=\sqrt{2}b_n=\sqrt{2}\coth(c_02^n)
$$

There remain only to determine $c_0$, we find

$$
c_0=\coth^{-1}b_0=\coth^{-1}\frac{a_0}{\sqrt{2}}=\coth^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{2}a_0}{2}
$$

so that finally,

$$
a_n=\sqrt{2}\coth\bigg( 2^n\coth^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{2}a_0}{2} \bigg)
$$

This should be able to help you prove the original claim.